# debian security /etc permissions

Tags: linux, debian, permissions

I'm setting up a debian box with shared webhhosts.
These users don't have ssh permissions, just ftp.
The users are allowed to use PHP and I setup `suphp` for that so the php processes runs under their own user account, etc.

I'm a little bit worried about the security of the system files, especially the `/etc` folder. I notice that most files in this directory have permissions like:

```
    drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    4096 Mar  4 20:00 pam.d
    -rw-r--r--  1 root root    1358 Mar  5 00:48 passwd
    -rw-------  1 root root    1358 Mar  5 00:48 passwd-
    drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    4096 Feb 18 14:22 pear
    drwxr-xr-x  4 root root    4096 Apr 29  2010 perl
    drwxr-xr-x  6 root root    4096 Feb 18 14:22 php5
    drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    4096 Mar  4 17:42 phpmyadmin
```

Are the read-world permissions which debian standard gives the files in `/etc` really needed? What's the best mask I can give those files? Are there any files in `/etc` that should be world readable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The default permissions are fine, and needed. If you e.g. didn't leave passwd world readable, a lot of user-related functionality would stop working. File such as /etc/shadow shouldn't be (and aren't) world readable.

Trust the OS to get this right, unless you know *very well* that the OS is wrong.

Comment: (...and if you go messing with permissions in /etc, have an alternate way of changing it back - even setting incorrect permissions there could make your OS unbootable)

Answer (score 4):

Nearly all the configuration file needs to be world readable, how do you expect your applications to read them otherwise ?

If you're really that paranoid, you can however create a groups for each application, put the needed users in them and change group owner and permission for the related configurations file. But I think this would cause a lot more harm than good.

The only important file I can think of which don't have world readable permission is /etc/shadow like stated in other comments.

If you want a secure Debian box, I suggest the [securing Debian Howto](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/securing-debian-howto/) it's a little bit old, but it gives a good overview.

There is also the [harden package](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/harden) which create some interesting dependencies and forbid installation of known vulnerable packages.

Answer (score 2):

Everything seams fine **except** the `phpmyadmin` directory. Be really careful to protect files so the mysql password do not leak.

Comment: I checked it out and it seems phpmyadmin configured this correctly, the file (config-db.php) in this folder which contains the password is not world-readable. Thanks for the sharpness :)

Answer (score 1):

The `passwd` needs to be world readable so that a few tools can work correctly. Despite its name, the passwords are not stored there, they are stored in the `/etc/shadow` file which should have the permissions `-rw-------`. The `passwd-` file is likely a backup. All other "files" are directories and contain configuration files.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a step back: If those users only need access to their home directories, most FTP servers have some config setting that *only* allows access to that directory, and nowhere else (most commonly by using chroot).

For example, in ProFTPd, it's the DefaultRoot directive:

```
<VirtualHost myhost.example.com>
  DefaultRoot ~
</VirtualHost>
```

http://www.proftpd.org/docs/faq/linked/faq-ch5.html#AEN524

Comment: Yes you are right and i do use this, althrough i'm afraid people upload a php script to access the file system (i do think suphp disabled this through)

Comment: @Danny Hiemstra: As far as I can see, suPHP can be configured to do likewise, using the `chroot` directive: http://www.suphp.org/DocumentationView.html?file=CONFIG